# Which test case causes the Runtime Error?

Tags: java, arrays, runtime-error, big-o

This was one of coding jam 2020 questions with the link attached below (round is complete), and while I could not reproduce it, the google engine reported that this was a runtime error even for the small test case. It could pretty much handle any test case I threw at it. Perhaps I am missing an edge case, but not sure what it is.

My understanding is that this is O(N) performance. All it really does is to check if the boolean sub array is free(false) and if so, assign the task to that sub array(true) with may be 2N compares.

https://codingcompetitions.withgoogle.com/codejam/round/000000000019fd27/000000000020bdf9

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

//Parenting Partnering Returns
public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)));
        int t = in.nextInt(); // Scanner has functions to read ints, longs, strings, chars, etc.
        for (int ijk = 1; ijk <= t; ++ijk) {

            int N = in.nextInt();
            String ans;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            boolean[] cal = new boolean[1442];
            boolean[] jal = new boolean[1442];
            int si, se;
            boolean canC,canJ, isPossible = true;

            for (int i = 0 ; i < N ; i++) {
                si = in.nextInt();
                se = in.nextInt();
                canC = false; canJ = false;

                if (cal[si + 1] == false && cal[se] == false || cal[si] == false && cal[se -1] == false) {
                    for (int j = si ; j <= se; j++) cal[j] = true;
                    sb.append('C'); canC = true; continue;

                } else if (jal[si + 1] == false && jal[se] == false || jal[si] == false && jal[se -1] == false) {
                    for (int k = si ; k <= se; k++) jal[k] = true;
                    sb.append('J'); canJ = true; continue;
                } else {
                    isPossible = false;
                    break;
                }
            }

            ans = sb.toString();

            if(isPossible)
            System.out.println("Case #" + ijk + ": " + ans);
            else System.out.println("Case #" + ijk + ": " + "IMPOSSIBLE");
        }
        //in.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: cal and jal are both an array of 1442 boolean elements.  first of all, you have to check if si and se indexes are between 0 and 1441.

Comment: Yes, both of them are always between 0 and 1440 inclusive as per the problem spec.

Comment: You can submit your code again (practice mode). The FAQ says "*Formally, you will receive a Runtime Error if your code does not finish with exit code 0*". Maybe you could try to add a `System.exit(0);`. Too bad if that's the reason :-(